# Overloading operator>> for case insensitive string

Tags: c++, case-insensitive, istream

Given the definition of ci_string from [cpp.reference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits), how would we go about implementing **operator>>**? My attempts at it involved std::read, but it doesn't seem to work (that is, gcount() properly counts the number of characters entered, but there is no output)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cctype> 
#include <string> 

// ci_string definition goes here 

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, ci_string& str)
{
    return in.read(&*str.begin(), 4); 
} 

int main()
{
    ci_string test_str; 
    std::cin >> test_str; 
    std::cout << test_str; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, ci_string& str)
{
    std::string tmp;
    in >> tmp;
    str.assign( tmp.begin(), tmp.end() ); 
    return in;
}
```

Comment: Splendid! Thank you, @Daniel Frey.

Comment: If you're going to go that route, I'd use `str.assign( tmp.begin(), tmp.end() )`, rather than the solution with `c_str`.  Why make the target recalculate the length when you alread know it?

Comment: @JamesKanze It's less readable but a good idea. I just wonder if todays compilers are smart enough to figure out taking the length from `tmp` directly in the above code as an optimization.

Comment: @DanielFrey Less readable?  Only to someone not used to working with the standard library---unlike the `c_str` method, it doesn't involve any of the special string functions, or a passage by the out of date C string.  (When _I_ see `c_str`, I read "legacy interface".  For me, using it elsewhere is obfuscation.)  As for the optimization, it's impossible.  (For that matter, your solution isn't correct if I'm reading from a file opened in binary mode that happens to contain a `'\0'`, and `isspace( '\0' )` returns false in the embedded locale.)

Comment: @JamesKanze OK, updated the answer. Too bad some conversions/assignments between `std::string` and `ci_string` don't work automatically, it would be so much nicer to be able to assign a `std::string` directly, probably even using `std::move(tmp)`. :(

Comment: @DanielFrey They are two unrelated types.  That's the way templates work.  I'd consider `str = ci_string( tmp.begin(), tmp.end() );` to be the most readable, but it costs an extra copy unless you can count on move semantics, which isn't the case for most people today.  Although in this case, maybe... it works even without move semantics, just slower, so you don't need to maintain two different versions.  It is slower without move semantics, but that will solve itself whenever the compiler gets upgraded.